# How to create entity class from synonyms in oracle?

Tags: oracle, jpa

i can create entity class from available tables but i want to create entity from synonyms in my oracle which are not showing in my table list...
(i have used eclipse JPA tools to create entity class)

how to see synonyms and create entity

Answer (score 0):

Whether Dali (the Eclipse plug-in that provides these JPA tools) can see and use table synonyms depends on the DTP extension you are using to access your database's metadata. If your synonyms show up in the Data Source Explorer under your database's "Tables" folder, they should show up in the Entity Generation wizard's list of tables. If they do not also show up in the  wizard, that is a possible bug.

Note: There are some third-party extensions that do *not* want Dali to use synonyms. You might look at this bug from a few years ago: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288027

Comment: I guess I have the same problem. I do not see any Synonyms in New JPA window. I don't have any tables all are Synonyms. How do I go about it.