# Is it possible to use Oracle Database Synonyms in Eclipse JPA tool

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, entity, dali

Using eclipse Dali JPA tools. When I try to create a new Entity from Database, it only tries to pull the table list. It does not list the Synonyms. In my db, all are synonyms. No tables. How do I get the list of Synonyms in this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you saw my [earlier response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426873/how-to-create-entity-class-from-synonyms-in-oracle/15436807). So the question remains: Do you see your synonyms in the Data Source Explorer under your database's "Tables" folder? If you do not see them (which I suspect is the case), the problem is with your DTP database "driver"; if you do see them, the problem is with the Dali Entity Generation tool.

Dali is at the mercy of the DTP "driver". That is, Dali sees only the tables reported by the DTP driver. It is up to the driver to determine whether the list of tables includes synonyms that are for tables. You might investigate whether there is a third-party DTP Oracle driver that can do what you need.

Comment: Not under the tables folder. But under synonyms.

Comment: Rats. That does not bode well for this problem. Dali is at the mercy of the DTP "driver". That is, Dali sees only the tables reported by the DTP driver. It is up to the driver to determine whether the list of tables includes synonyms that are for tables. You might investigate whether there is a third-party DTP Oracle driver that can do what you need.

Comment: Please add this in the answer as well so it may be helpful for someone

Comment: netbeans has a bug filed for it too https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230012

Comment: I didn t found a good oracle driver for this aim, but I used a workaround, creating a view for each synonyms table to use these views to generate JPA code. Then I rename the view name with the synonyms