# Joining two entities with another entity (association) - Hibernate / JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, entity

I have 3 entities.

```
Member:
  mem_id;
  mem_name;

  @OneToOne  
  Address address;// ???!?!?
  ....
Customer:
  cust_id // PK
  mem_id // FK to member.member_id
  type; //needed field
  ....
Addr
  cust_id // FK to customer.cust_id.

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Customer customer;
  ....
```

I need 2 things:

1. When I load Member, I need address of that Member, which is through Customer entity.
2. I also need `type` value from for the Member entity

How should map these entities? What is the strategy?

Comment: what database? if you have tables, netbeans would generate stuff for you

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Oracle 11g enterprise. Eclipse IDE.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm

Comment: @KalpeshSoni please check the updated question. Address has Customer as a child entity. Thanks!

Comment: do you already have the tables in databse, if so, have you tried generating the entities using the IDE?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Yes I do have those tables. But I cannot generate because all db elements are under Synonyms and Dali tool cannot list Synonym. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133717/is-it-possible-to-use-oracle-database-synonyms-in-eclipse-jpa-tool) is the issue

Comment: if you connect with sql developer, you can see the create table script generated by it in the last tab, can you post it in the question?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni. Not sure what you would like to see. Did you mean, you wanted to see SCHEMA definition for the above tables? Or something else?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I wish I could provide full schema. Each table has a lot of more fields than I listed here. Does having a schema help you in any way to answer this question?

Comment: this is jpa 101 , so i feel like i am missing something

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Addr does not have a PK. It just has FK. So its not straightforward.

Comment: what uniquely identifies an address? composite pk are fine

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Composite key (cust_id, which is a FK and another field called address type).

Comment: I know this is not the answer you want, if I were in your shoes, I would install oracle XE in local machine, put tables instead of synonyms, fire up netbeans and generate entities

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I get the point. Thanks.  Just trying to get an insight from people with off hand experience with this situation.